# Javascript Regex for matching string between strings and a specific length

Tags: javascript, regex

How should I write regex to extract a substring from a string with the following conditions:

- Starting character should be `A`
- Last 2 characters should be `00`.
- Total length of string should be between 7 to 8
- Only numbers

Meaning `A` + 12345678 + `00`

eg: Input: `ABC12345678CRP1234567F2801209A1234567800<<<33`

Output: `12345678`

So far, I have tried below regex, but seems like I am missing something?

`/(A(.*)00)/` (this fails because it doesnt match with the correct length

`/(A(.*)00){7,8}/` (im not sure why this fails, but the idea was to keep the same as before and add the length restriction)

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably, `A(\d+)00` [is enough](https://regex101.com/r/Wh6l54/1).

Comment: I believe you mean, "The string must be preceded by 'A' and followed by '00'". As stated 'A' and '00' are part of the string that contains 7-8 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
A\d{7,8}00
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`A`** - Matches `A` literally.
- **`\d{7,8}`** - Matches digit 7 to 8 times.
- **`00`** - Matches `00` literally.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/Rjwfct/2)

```js
let string = `ABC12345678CRP1234567F2801209A1234567800<<<33`;
const regex = /A(\d{7,8})00/gm;

console.log(regex.exec(string)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this regex: `/(A(\d{8})00|(A(\d{7})00))/gm`

Explanation:

- `A(\d{8})00`: Starts with "A" and has 8 digits and ends with "00", or
- `|`: Or
- `(A(\d{7})00)`: Starts with "A" and has 7 digits and ends with "00", or

You will get the full match ("A########00" or "A#########00")in the second group and only the number ("########" or "#########") in the second group.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Ml1xih/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=A)(\d{7,8})(?=00)
```

`(?<=A)` Positive lookbehind will make sure the matching string contains **A** 
`(?=00)`    Positive lookahead will make sure the string is followed by **00**

https://regex101.com/r/nP0Qu0/1